# Upload CSV to Azure SQL or Blob Storage on button click

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications, azure-sql-database

I am in the process of creating a web app that will let users upload a CSV file to a Azure SQL database or a blob storage container, whatever can be done with JavaScript. I don't have a lot of experience with programming and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

So far, all I have is a simple HTML webpage with the buttons I need:
[image]

As of right now, clicking `Choose File` will open file explorer so a user can upload their csv file. My goal is that when a user chooses a file and clicks `Submit`, the file that they upload (CSV Only) will be imported into a SQL table that I will create.

Is this possible with JavaScript? If so, can anyone give me an example of how to achieve this, or let me know if I need to use a different language to do so?

I was hoping it would be something like this:

```
<input type="file" id="upload1">
<input onclick="upload()" id="submitMain" type="submit">
```

```
function upload(){
    //upload file to SQL
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below link using .NET. You might want to customize it a bit based on your requirements if needed.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-export-import-excel-blob-to-from-db